# How to setup Backand SDK in an Ionic2 app?

Tags: ionic2, backand

I'd like to setup my Ionic2 app to use the Backand SDK. I am new to Ionic2 / Angular2 and I couldn't find any example out there with an Ionic2 app. I could only find example apps with Ionic1 / Angular1 apps which don't help me.

Any clues?

Thanks, Guillaume

Comment: https://github.com/backand/ionic2-crud-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Aaron said, you can take 'backandService.ts' file from /app/service folder in my repository at

https://github.com/backand/ionic2-crud-example

[Here](https://github.com/backand/ionic2-crud-example/blob/master/app/services/backandService.ts) you have direct link to file.

If you are using Typescript, you will be able to load it with this snippet:

```
import {BackandService} from '../../services/backandService'
```

Inject BackandService in you constructor:

```
constructor(public backandService:BackandService) {   
}
```

And do login like this:

```
this.backandService.getAuthTokenSimple(this.username, this.password);
```

And then post data with this code:

```
this.backandService.postItem(this.name)
```